# Remove a character in the middle of the string

Tags: php, regex

Suppose we have the lines `1234H242343`,`6334H345345`, etc. I need a regular expression to get the strings `1234242343`,`6334345345`, etc. The character may vary (not always `H`), but in this case, the `H` character. The most important thing is that the resulting string be in ONE subpattern with the number `1`. Otherwise, the task is elementary.

I would like something like this -

`(\ d + (? = H) (? <= H) \ d +)`

But this design does not work for unknown reasons. Although separately it will work -

`(\ d + (? = H))`

`((? <= H) \ d +)`

The variant with a non-catching substitute is also unsuitable because the symbol will still get to the general result -

`(\ d + (? = H) (?: H) (? <= H) \ d +)`

I think there is a solution. Help me find )

PS: For example -

```
preg_match ('((\d+)H(\d+))', '1234H242343', $matches);
<pre>
Array
    (
        [0] => 1234H242343
        [1] => 1234 // one subpattern
        [2] => 242343 // two subpattern
    )
</pre>
```

I need a solution for the result

```
 <pre>
 Array
     (
         [0] => 1234H242343
         [1] => 1234242343 // one subpattern
     )
 </pre>
```

Comment: Is the character always `H`?

Comment: No, but in this case it does not matter. It is always a single character.

Comment: I'd solve it using `str_replace` which is a lot cleaner IMO. `echo str_replace('H','','1234H242343');` If you have more characters change the `'H'` to an array of letters `['H','Q','P']`.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by ONE submask.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @jonnyjandles I mean Subpattern https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

Comment: @Dave it is not a problem to solve the task as otherwise. I need a solution using a regular expression. This is a difficult task.

Comment: I added an example to the question

Comment: @SeanBright this is not a regular expression

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to get exactly what you want using standard regex groups.

Comment: I also do not see how you can do it with sub-patterns.  I don't see how a sub-pattern can remove a character.

Comment: @SeanBright I also do not see a solution. But it is possible.

Comment: @SeanBright because this task has the answer

Comment: @SeanBright this is a test task that has a solution.

Comment: Definitely no. You can't obtain a group without a character in the middle of the string using `preg_match` (that is only able to return substrings). You probably misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

This will use regex to remove any **letters** (a-zA-Z).

```
$string = '12394H2304';
$pattern = '#\D#';
$replacement = '';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, that is what is mentioned in the question. `The most important thing is that the resulting string be in ONE subpattern with the number 1. Otherwise, the task is elementary.`

Comment: 'with the number one' is confusing since it seems not all the inputs have the number one.

Comment: @jonnyjandles I added an example to the question